# Magento 2 - Unlimited stock of a product

Tags: magento2, product, out-of-stock

Our products are digital goods which do not have a quantity limited. Is there a way to configure a product with a unlimited stock quantity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can easily do this by visiting your Advanced Inventory Tab of your product.

Just set `Manage Stock` option to `No`[image]

**EDIT**

---

If your store contain all digital products then you can set below option by default, so you don't need to set for individual product

```
Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options
```

`Manage Stock` to `No`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In **Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog ->Inventory tab**.

Set **Manage stock** to **NO** in Product stock options

**manage_stock** - to control a stock quantity of a product set 1.
 By setting 0 you allow  Magento 2 to consider a product has an unlimited stock level.